# Going through a dictionary via a for loop and counting the number of events

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
d={a': [True]}
{'b': [True]}
{'c': [True]}
{'d': [True, False, True]}
```

I want to count the number of true and false for each letter and then output the ratio of true/false for each data .
Example For d: Number of true=2 and Number of false = 1 . It should print a ratio of 2/1=1
to do that,
I've done this so far:

[image: MY CODE]

but it keeps outputting zero. why?

Comment: Paste your code, not an image of it please

Comment: `2/1=1` sure ? Nope

Comment: In addition to the image problem, there is a quoting issue in the code you shared. We can't be expected to guess which errors are relevant and which are typos. Please make sure to share _accurate_ information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are `bool` type `True/False` and you compare them to `str` type `'True'`, so everything will be evaluated to `False`, it should be

```
if l: 
    count_s +=1 
else:
    count_f +=1
```

---

A `collections.Counter` could be very useful too

```
d = {'a': [True], 'b': [True], 'c': [True], 'd': [True, False, True], 'e': [False]}

for edge, values in d.items():
    c = Counter(values)
    ratio = c.get(True, 0) / c.get(False, 1)
    print(edge, ratio)

a 1.0
b 1.0
c 1.0
d 2.0
e 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `True` (a boolean) with `"True"` (a string). Removing the quotes around `True` in the if clause should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The string `"True"` is not the same as the boolean `True`.

Since `True` counts as 1 and `False` as 0, you can simply use `sum`:

```
d = {
    'a': [True],
    'b': [True],
    'c': [True],
    'd': [True, False, True],
}

for edge, values in d.items():
    count_true = sum(values)
    count_false = len(values) - count_true
    success = count_true / count_false if count_false > 0 else 0
    print(edge, success)
```